# how to diplay file field and image field on pythonaywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am using Django1.8 and I need help. how to display images and files on pythonanywhere by using model filefield and imagefield.
on my development server everything is ok.but during de production I have donne everything these two field.the parodox is bootstrap is well integread.
my project is on githb: Geyd/eces_edu.git
help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually serve the files. On your local machine, Django is serving static files for you. On PythonAnywhere, it is not. There is extensive documentation on the PythonAnywhere help pages to get you started with configuring static files.